# Alert me Logical Architecture of SharePoint Farm -- Security Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a question about Logical Architecture of SharePoint Farm , My topology design consists of 3 tiers:

- Front Servers
- Application Servers
- DB Servers

As you know we need to run **Windows SharePoint Services Web Application** service on web front servers. There is a connection between Web Front Servers and DB servers and there was a discussion between SharePoint Team and security team in our organization about direct connection between Front Serves and DB Servers.

Now my question is, why should there be a direct connection between Front Servers and DB Servers?

Answer (score 3):

Front end servers not only run Foundation Web service, but also the Timer Service (sptimerv4) which must communicate with SQL databases directly. Yes, SharePoint is secure if you set it up as such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with architecture like yours. I typically use two servers one as a Front End / App Server / SharePoint Server and second as Database SQL Server. I run anti-virus software on both servers and both servers are under main domain controller. SharePoint is sync with **Active Directory** to spread correct permission for users.

Correct me if I missed your point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are spinning your wheels, why would that be a security concern? The architecture you described is a normal, even recommended, setup. SharePoint stores all the content you see, from service applications, to content, to the central administration, to configuration, in databases. SharePoint has it's built in security model that will work just fine on the outside if it's set up correctly. There are many SharePoint public facing servers from companies, and they work just fine and have no security concerns. Some are big Fortune 500 companies. If they did have concerns, they would not be running SharePoint in a public facing environment.